# Firebase Deployment using Github Action

Tags: firebase, github, firebase-cli, github-actions

I'm trying to deploy my code using Github's actions to firebase.

I am receiving this error

```
    success Installed "firebase-tools@7.11.0" with binaries:
      - firebase
Done in 12.99s.
/home/runner/work/_temp/30a2b6cb-a097-4d73-ac92-5379d0cc6ccf.sh: line 2: firebase: command not found
```

my code for deploy is as following

```
deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: dist
      - name: yarn add firebase-tools
        run: |
          yarn global add firebase-tools
          firebase deploy ${{ secrets.firebase_token }} --only hosting:**** --non-interactive
        env:
          PROJECT_ID: ****
```

how can I add firebase-tools globally?

I tried https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-firebase

But getting Error

```
setting firebase project to ***
Now using project ***

=== Deploying to '***'...

i  deploying hosting

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: *******************

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
##[error]Docker run failed with exit code 2
```

Here is the code for this.

```
deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: dist
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting:****
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.firebase_token }}
          PROJECT_ID: ****
```

Comment: Have you see the documentation? https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-firebase

Comment: Yeah, I was trying with `w9jds/firebase-action` but getting this error there. ```Error: An unexpected error has occurred. ##[error]Docker run failed with exit code 2```

Comment: If you want to call the firebase command yourself, you could add the `firebase-tools` to your dev-dependencies, install your dependencies via `npm ci` and then call the firebase command with `npx` prefixed (see here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx). This will then take the installed version from the `node_modules/.bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Docker run failed with exit code 2
> ```

That was reported in [`w9jds/firebase-action` issue 17](https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/issues/17)

> For me it works when I remove "`--only hosting:prod`".
>   Probably it depends on the plan.
>
> You can't keep `--only hosting:prod` unless you have your site setup for multi-domain hosting inside of your `firebase.json` file and one of the sites that you can deploy is called `prod`.

Comment: In my hosting, there are two sites. I want to deploy in one of them. here is my firebase.json


{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public/site_name",   
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

may be something is wrong here

Comment: @AwaisNawaz `hosting:****`: the `***` would need to match one of the site names.

Comment: I use `w9jds/firebase-action` and I'm trying to understand what exactly is deployed to firebase. Is it the `build` directory only or the whole rep ? I can't find an answer in the firebase doc and neither in the action's code.

Comment: @JohnDoe you mean https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action? As seen here, it can deploy what you have uploaded: https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/issues/20. It deploys the artifact build and uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to follow this way!

```
name: Build and deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
    
  # Run workflow manually
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build & Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@main
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Build dependencies
        run: npm run build
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

You can replace npm commands with your yarn commands, and it should work fine.